# Laravel problem showing added unnecessary character while running on localhost server f character comes always when running

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem in Laravel project while running in localhost server:

One character comes automatically and I have and screenshot f character comes before running server flocalhost::8000, and I want to get rid out of this.

I tried `php artian cache:clear`, `config:clear`, `route:clear`, `view:clear`,`composer dump-autoload`

```
php artisan serve
```

**flocalhost::8000**

Answer (score 0):

Delete vendor folder, then run

```php
composer install
```